# PrimeNG P-ListBox throwing error upon selection

Tags: angular, primeng

Upon selecting an item from my listbox module i am getting an error thrown for some reason the value keeps coming in as an object instead of an array to my listbox.js which is from p-listbox from PrimeNG

HTML:

```
<p-listbox formControlName="programType" [options]="phoneTypeItems"  multiple="multiple" [style]="{'width':'350px'}" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'150px'}"
                     checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter">

                    </p-listbox>
```

.TS:

```
import { ListboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

export class SearchCareResultsComponent {

phoneTypeItems = [{ label: 'Mobile', value: '1' }, { label: 'Work', value: '2' }, { label: 'Home', value: '3' }]

}
```

Here is the error:

> Listbox.html:28 ERROR TypeError: this.value.concat is not a function
>       at Listbox.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/listbox/listbox.js.Listbox.onCheckboxClick
>   (listbox.js:277)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Listbox.html:28)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12014)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13063)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8607)
>       at core.es5.js:9218
>       at HTMLDivElement. (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)

Picture of the UI and error location:
[image]

Comment: i posted the snippet that is generating that p-listbox (the html and .ts portion)  the whole code is way too big and i do not think it is relevant ( i thinK)

Comment: it seems to be an issue with the primeng, but the issue lies in your array. create a  demo and reproduce the issue

Comment: @sajeetharan how can I create a demo

Comment: The problem might be that the value that is attached to the programType formControl is an object instead of an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PrimeNG you are using ?

Maybe try the documentation from [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox).

Try with simple cities object if it works for you.

```
this.cities1 = [
            {label:'Select City', value:null},
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}}
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];


<p-listbox [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" filter="filter"></p-listbox>
```